# How t check if a value is undefined in a matrix?

Tags: ti-nspire

I have a matrix ratiotest:= [undef;undef;4].

```
Local i
Local ratiotest

for i,1,rowDim(ratiotest),1
 if ratiotest[i] = "undef" Then
  ∞→ratiotest[i]
 end if
endfor
```

But I get `"Error: Variable is not defined"`

Is there anyway to detect a undefined variable ? Im am missing something in the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the construct `IfFn`. The fourth argument will be returned if the
first argument is undefined. Therefore

```
IfFn(x,false, false, true)
```

is true only for x being undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and soegaard's solution is not working. The only thing i could do is to transform expression into string and test it for being "undef". This piece of code will return list2, where undef elements of list1 are replaced with 0.

```
for i1,1,dim(list1)
    list_str:=string(list1[i1])
    list2[i1]:=iffn(list_str="undef",0,list1[i1])
endfor
```

Comment: That is a great workaround, i ll test it later on and ley you know if it works!

Comment: Ok, but one more thing - if you want to check the whole matrix/list for undef elements, because you might not want to enter the loop if there isnt any, the next line will do it:
`instring(string(list1),"undef")`
This will return 0 if no element is undef